# How to fix DriveApp.getFiles() ... file.getName() crashes logger (google script API)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am running a simplest function:

```
function listGDfiles() {
 // Log the name of every file in the user's Drive.
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getName());
}
}
```

It takes a long while. after that I get "There was a failure getting the log.Dismiss".  I am able to print a single name to the logger if I take off the while loop.  What is wrong?

I am running google script and writing in the script editor off a google sheet. Is it always associated with the google sheet I started with? Does that slow the whole thing down? Can I work on the code without a connection to the google sheet that, right now, seems to be the backbone of the "project"?

there is like 5 files in the drive with simple names...

Comment: Well, your question is somewhat broad (too many subquestions packed in)... As for the main issue, `Logger` under new runtime (I assume you are using V8) is riddled with issues, and the file iterator is not known for its stability as well. You can start this issue and provide details for Google to consider it a higher priority issue (but probably it won't be fixed, as new editor is in the works, so they probably won't bother with the old one): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149519063

Comment: As for the second, yes, you can - a document is not very relevant to the script (and it is usually better to create standalone scripts unless it helps with narrowing auth scopes), you can read this guide to get a hang of script types: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone

Comment: On that note, if you use `console` and switch the project to use standard GCP, you can use StackDriver logging, which is usually fast and more or less reliable (at least this is my experience)

Comment: @Oleg Valter - very helpful . thank you

Comment: makmak - my pleasure. I think you are better off with a combination of the advanced Drive service and/or Drive API + StackDriver logging (that is until we get the rest fixed, but that is unlikely)